# Using count for two different values in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

In the following query I am trying to fetch data from tables: `company`, `classes_by_company`, and `person`. I have a foreign key in all tables with the name `company_id`.  In the `classes_by_company` table a class  can have a `class_status`  that can be either `active` or `inactive`.  The same goes for table `person` with its corresponding `person_status`. I am able to count the total number of classes and  the total number of persons, find the working query here: [SQFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/803440/12). In the query below I am trying to incorporate the previous query but now also count the total number of `class_status=ACTIVE` and `person_status=ACTIVE`. I am getting error `Not unique table/alias: 'c'`. How can I can count the total number and the total number of active classes and person? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b73/5)

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id, a.status, c.class_status, p.person_status,
       c.total_count AS classes_per_company,
       p.total_count AS employees_per_company,
       c.active_count AS active_classes,
       p.active_count AS active_instructors
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as total_count 
           FROM classes_by_company
           GROUP BY company_id) c
       ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as active_count
           FROM classes_by_company
           WHERE class_status = 'ACTIVE'
           GROUP BY company_id) c
       ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as total_count
           FROM person
           GROUP BY company_id) p
       ON a.company_id = p.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as active_count
           FROM person
           WHERE person_status = 'ACTIVE'
           GROUP BY company_id) p
       ON a.company_id = c.company_id
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE company
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     company_id int,
     status varchar(20)
    );
CREATE TABLE classes_by_company
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
 company_id int,
 class_name varchar(20),
 class_status varchar(20) 
);
CREATE TABLE person
(
 id int auto_increment primary key,
employee_id int,
 company_id int,
 person_name varchar(20),
 person_status varchar(20)
);
```

Comment: You can't use the same alias for two subqueries.  Make one subquery cactive and the other ctotal...you'll have to do the same with the p's too.

Comment: Next you will run into the issue that you are referencing fields in your initial SELECT clause that don't exist in your joined subqueries (i.e. c.class_status, p.person_status)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query structure is fine, you just need to give different aliases to each subquery that you join with.

You also failed to return `class_status` and `person_status` from the `c` and `p` subqueries.

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id, a.status, c.class_status, p.person_status,
       c.total_count AS classes_per_company,
       p.total_count AS employees_per_company,
       ca.active_count AS active_classes,
       pa.active_count AS active_instructors
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, class_status, COUNT(*) as total_count 
           FROM classes_by_company
           GROUP BY company_id) c
       ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as active_count
           FROM classes_by_company
           WHERE class_status = 'ACTIVE'
           GROUP BY company_id) ca
       ON a.company_id = ca.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, person_status, COUNT(*) as total_count
           FROM person
           GROUP BY company_id) p
       ON a.company_id = p.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as active_count
           FROM person
           WHERE person_status = 'ACTIVE'
           GROUP BY company_id) pa
       ON a.company_id = pa.company_id
```

I changed the aliases to `ca` for active classes, and pa for active person.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b73/15)

You can also reduce the number of joins by counting the active rows in the same query as the total rows:

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id, a.status, c.class_status, p.person_status,
       c.total_count AS classes_per_company,
       p.total_count AS employees_per_company,
       c.active_count AS active_classes,
       p.active_count AS active_instructors
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, class_status, COUNT(*) as total_count, SUM(class_status = 'ACTIVE') as active_count
           FROM classes_by_company
           GROUP BY company_id) c
       ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, person_status, COUNT(*) as total_count, SUM(person_status = 'ACTIVE') as active_count
           FROM person
           GROUP BY company_id) p
       ON a.company_id = p.company_id
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4b73/16)

Comment: Oh failed to do so with the aliases but now I am aware. Thank you. What is your input about `id` as auto increment? is it necessary to have this for "numerical order"?

Comment: Auto-increment IDs aren't necessary if you have some other unique identifier for the rows. But you should probably study up on database normalization to understand the reason why they're popular.

Answer (score 0):

Very small change...table alias's (or subqueries) cannot be the same

```
SELECT a.id, a.company_id, a.status, c.class_status, p.person_status,
   c.total_count AS classes_per_company,
   p.total_count AS employees_per_company,
   ca.active_count AS active_classes,
   pa.active_count AS active_instructors
FROM company a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as total_count 
       FROM classes_by_company
       GROUP BY company_id) c
   ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as active_count
       FROM classes_by_company
       WHERE class_status = 'ACTIVE'
       GROUP BY company_id) ca
   ON a.company_id = c.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as total_count
       FROM person
       GROUP BY company_id) p
   ON a.company_id = p.company_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT company_id, COUNT(*) as active_count
       FROM person
       WHERE person_status = 'ACTIVE'
       GROUP BY company_id) pa
   ON a.company_id = c.company_id
```